# strtotime(07/19/2011 00:00)

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Trying to convert a date & time value in the format of "07/19/2011 00:00" using the php function "strtotime()".

Doesn't seem to like the structure of the date time. Does anyone know how I can convert this to a timestamp for MySQL database?

```
$convertstart = strtotime($_POST['start']);
$start = mysql_real_escape_string($convertstart);
$convertend = strtotime($_POST['end']);
$end = mysql_real_escape_string($convertend);
```

Thanks!

EDIT also...

When I convert today's date( 07/31/2011 18:35 ) I get back 2013-12-15 17:00:00 in the MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not let MySQL take care of it for you. Try out MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. It uses the same format specifiers as the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Try this: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07/31/2011 18:35', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');`

It should give you a time-stamp compatible with MySQL DATETIME fields. For me it returns: `2011-07-31 18:35:00`

Comment: Thanks this is what I need. However I'm not sure how to implement the function in my php code. Does anyone have a useful link. I don't have much xp with MySQL.

Comment: Check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp for an introduction to using MySQL with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

That date format is too ambiguous to be parsed automatically. You'll need to parse that format explicitly using, for example, [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php):

```
$p = strptime($date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($p['tm_hour'], $['tm_min'], 0, $p['tm_mon'], $p['tm_mday'], $p['tm_year']));
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use PHP's date function combined with strotime() to create a valid MySQL-timestamp.

$sqlend = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end));

Comment: Original poster mentioned that `strtottime()` doesn't work correctly, since the time-stamp isn't in the correct format.

Comment: echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("07/31/2011 18:35")); returns 2011-07-31 18:35:00 for me